# Understanding ON DELETE NO ACTION in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, referential-integrity

I have a referential integrity constraint on between table `SRS_INST_CODE` and `SRS_INSTRUMENT`. I found the `ON DELETE` rule using the following query:

```
 SELECT a.table_name, c.delete_rule, c_pk.table_name parent_table
 FROM all_cons_columns a, 
 all_constraints c,
 all_constraints c_pk
 WHERE  a.owner = c.owner
 AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
 AND c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
 AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
 AND c.constraint_type = 'R'
 AND a.table_name = 'SRS_INST_CODE';
```

The output is:

```
SRS_INST_CODE   NO ACTION   SRS_INSTRUMENT
```

However I am able to delete from `SRS_INSTRUMENT` even though there are records in `SRS_INST_CODE` that refer to the deleted record. Also the records in `SRS_INST_CODE` are deleted as well. I expect this to be the case for `ON DELETE CASCADE` and not `ON DELETE NO ACTION` . What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure - but can you re-run that query with the following added to the  SELECT clause: `SELECT a.table_name, c.delete_rule, c_pk.table_name parent_table, c.deferrable, c.deferred, c.validated`

Comment: I get this result - `SRS_INST_CODE NO ACTION SRS_INSTRUMENT NOT DEFERRABLE IMMEDIATE VALIDATED`

Comment: Hmm ok - no idea at this stage. One thing I'd do is try dropping and re-creating the constraint (assuming you're in a dev instance) and running the test again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete record by simple `DELETE` DML query, 
then most probable reason of such behaviour is trigger on `SRS_INSTRUMENT` that deletes corresponding records from `SRS_INST_CODE`
You may check this by following query:

```
SELECT * FROM user_triggers WHERE table_name = 'SRS_INSTRUMENT';
```

Comment: Thats correct. Only I had to query all_triggers instead of user_triggers. Thanks.